# How to Group specific Colomn in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Please help me out to resolve my doubt,Am getting an output like this in oracle9i,

```
S.No    Column1      Column2  
----    ----------   -------
 1      10/11/2011   Basic   
 2      10/11/2011   Basic       
 3      12/05/2012   Basic       
 4      12/05/2012   Basic       
 5      13/05/2012   Basic
```

But My real scenario is , i need to populate the output in below structure

```
S.No    Column1      Column2  
----    ----------   -------
 1      10/11/2011   Basic   
        10/11/2011   Basic       
 2      12/05/2012   Basic       
        12/05/2012   Basic       
 3      13/05/2012   Basic
```

I dont know how to form the query , to retrieve the structure, please help me out,  please anyone provide the solution for me..Thanks in advance

Comment: are you joining two tables?

Comment: Nopes its a single table

Comment: So you mean you have `2 records` for 1 `S.No`?

Comment: YES 2 RECORDS SINGLE S.NO

Comment: Actually I don't get the sense why you have to do it that way. You can do it in front end but on the sql, it is possible but difficult.

Comment: i AM VERY CURIOUS TO KNOW THE LOGIC, PLEASE HELP ME OUT

Comment: What is your front-end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN r = 1
             THEN w
          ELSE NULL
       END as s_no, column1, column2
  FROM (SELECT column1, column2,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2) AS r,
               DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS d
          FROM SAMPLE);
```

Here [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310) function returns unique number for each row within a group of column1.
[DENSE_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions052.htm#i1064409) function returns unique rank to to each group of column1.
Using this, you can chose to display the dense_rank column only for 1st row.

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e5fe/4)